Establish Two Connections to a Server in Finder (MacOS 15)
I have a network server "TechR" that I need to connect to using different credentials at the same time. To access different files/shared folders.
How can I establish multiple connections in Finder on MacOS 15.1.1?

You can connect to the same file server multiple times with different usernames using this procedure on macOS 15.1.1:

In the Finder, choose the Go menu, then select Connect to Server.

Type the network address for the computer or server in the Server Address field in the following format:


smb://other_username:*@server.name.here
Note: The " * " part of the smb:// URL is to trigger the server login window for your SMB server, so that the password for the other_username account can be entered.

Click the Connect button.

Enter the desired username and password when prompted.


Username: other_username
Password: The current account password for other_username

Select the share on your SMB server that you want to use.

WARNING: Do not try to mount the same share twice using different usernames.
One way you can verify that you’re actually connected using different usernames is to use the mount command in Terminal. This should show all mounted volumes on the Mac, including mounted fileshares. The fileshare mount information should include which account was used to mount the share.

macOS 15's Finder does not intentionally support multiple connections, with differing credentials, to the same share. See Rich's answer for a work around.
A reliable approach is to use a remote file browsing application, such as CyberDuck, to connect an additional time to an SMB drive.
