Can macOS connect to a server with 2 different user/folder access?
I have a QNAP NAS which contains some photos. It also has Time Machine set up and working.
I connect from macOS to the QNAP server using a custom QNAP user account.
I'd like RW access to the other folders. The custom QNAP user account does not have permissions to R or W the extra folders.
Am I able to connect to the same server with a 2nd QNAP account which does have RW access to those folders?
AFAIK, macOS doesn't allow this.
Help appreciated.

Are you connecting via Samba/SMB to the NAS? Does the question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/477208 help? If not, we can reopen this question.

This may be more a QNAP than a macOS question. Can you create a QNAP account which has access to all the directories you need?

Perfect, thanks @GrahamMiln
